# required attribute not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hii im doing contact us form without refreshing the page. But after i click on the send button even the fields are empty my required attribute is not working. Please help me

contact.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){

$.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {   
 $('#success').html(response);
 //$('#success').hide('slow');
});
return false;


});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="mycontactform" class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Contact Us</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name"  name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message"  cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
        </li>
<li>
            <input type="button"  class="submit" style="width:70px; text-align:center; height:30px; margin-left:200px; cursor:pointer"  value="SEND" id="submit" />


        </li><div id="success" style="color:red;"></div>
</form>
</body>
```

send.php

```
<?php

// Here we get all the information from the fields sent over by the form.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = 'babloopuneeth@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message;
    $headers = 'From: youremail@domain.com' . "\r\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
    echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}else{
    echo "Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.";
}
?>
```

above is my code. please help me. I want required attribute to be worked on clicking the button.

Comment: What do you mean by `required` not working .. Check if the request is being sent

Comment: What browser are you using?  Are you sure it supports HTML5's `required`?

Comment: What browser are you using? `required` is an HTML5 attribute, older browsers may not support it.

Comment: Keep in mind that `required` is only working in IE 10 (and higher), Firefox, Chrome and Opera (not in Safari). If you're using jQuery: there are a lot of form validation plugins.

Comment: @Pieter It also works in Chrome.

Comment: @Sushanth-- means if i click on my send button, the email is sent even though the required fields are empty..

Comment: @Pieter: Ya im using latest version of Firefox

Comment: @PuneethP OK, but hopefully you try to support all commonly used browsers?

Comment: you are using jquery ajax calls they do not check the required attributes unless you tell it to, as has been answered on your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my opinion, but I'd use PHP to check if the input fields are empty or not.

Just having a if statement to see if they are filled out works just fine.

```
<?php

// Here we get all the information from the fields sent over by the form.
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if($name=='' || $email=='' || $message=='') { //Make sure all of the fields are not empty
echo "Please fill in all of the fields";
}
else { //If they are filled in, process the rest of the form

$to = 'babloopuneeth@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: youremail@domain.com' . "\r\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
    echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}else{
    echo "Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.";
}
}
?>
```